# What is Eclipse's Ctrl+Alt+J shortcut equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

What is Eclipse's Ctrl+Alt+J shortcut equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?

I don't have to have to go to every method & variable and do /** ENTER

Answer (score 2):

Intellij doesn't have a shortcut for this, so you need to assign one to the "**Fix doc comment**" command.

Simply go to *Settings -> IDE Settings -> Keymap*, search for *"Fix doc comment"* and assign the shortcut of your choice. Feel free to use `Alt+Shift+J`, as it doesn't seem to be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

in Search EveryWhere (typing shift key twice) find Join line.

you want set hotkey about Join line, then Setting -> Keymap -> find Join line, and set hotkey

Comment: What do you set the hotkey to though?

Comment: i don't use join line. but default set is ctrl + shift + j

Comment: This isn't what I'm after.

Comment: The questioner asked for the wrong shortcut: he meant `Alt+Shift+J` in eclipse for _"Add Javadoc Comment"_  ;-)